# Присоединить данные из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Не могу что-то даже сформулировать конкретно вопрос, чтобы найти ответ в интернетах.

Есть таблица *appeals* со столбцами **idAppeal**,  **userId** и **closeUserId**.

Есть таблица *users* со столбцами  **idUser** и **nickname**. 
 Делаю запрос и приклеиваю **nickname** через *left join* для **closeUserId**

```
SELECT  a.userId, a.closeUserId, u.nickname as userClosedName
FROM appeals a
left join users u on u.idUser = a.closeUserId   
WHERE a.idAppeal = :idAppeal
```

Все работает но теперь нужно в результирующей таблице отображалось так же **nickname** для **userId**

 Напролом через *UNION* можно сделать, но я уверен что есть более короткое и красивое решение до которого я не могу пока что дойти

Comment: Ну сделайте ещё один джойн, только уже по другому условию....странный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT  a.userId, a.closeUserId, u.nickname as userClosedName, u1.nuickname as userName
FROM appeals a
left join users u on u.idUser = a.closeUserId   
left join users u1 on u1.idUser = a.userId   
WHERE a.idAppeal = :idAppeal
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: У меня этот способ не получался тк забыл поменять псевдоним для второго джоина. Пора отдохнуть)
Спасибо!